# NetSuite purchase order generated automatically from sales order from drop ship or special order to use item description as modified on sales order

Tags: netsuite

NetSuite purchase order generated automatically from sales order from drop ship or special order to use item description as modified on sales order.

The purchase order is calling the item description from a item stored table, I need the modified item description as written from the sales order where the purchase order originated from to be used as the item description as the new purchase order is generated.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a userevent on the PO, which uses the "create" type to restrict the process to just newly created POs.
There you can use the "createdfrom" field to find the SO that created this PO, and match the item lines, finally overwriting the PO line item descriptions from the corresponding lines in the SO.